# Kubuntu 17.04 booting into tty1 instead of GUI

Tags: boot, tty, kubuntu

My Kubuntu 17.04 is booting into tty1 instead of GUI. When I reboot while the machine is running, everything works fine. I can also switch to the graphical interface but it starts in tty1 for most of the time.

Comment: you say , you can switch to graphical interface . This means you have a Display Manager and a ".xinitrc" in your $HOME ?


Also check the content of "/etc/default/grub"  and verify the variable  "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT"

What is the content ?

Comment: /var/log/Xorg.0.log may give you an idea why the graphics engine does not start